# IOS device not populating a click function attribute addition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, function, click

For some reason when I click on a button that triggers a menu to open, an added attribute source does not populate the defined image with IOS mobile/tablets via a browser (I tried Chrome).

I searched around for a solution. I saw someone recommend adding "touchend" to my click function and I did, but it did not help. `$('.requestButton').on('click touchend', function (event) {`

I'm not sure how to demo this situation, since it is only happening on IOS mobile/tablet devices.

[Click here to see it live](https://mbkit.com/catalogs)

Scroll down to where you see the section below. Click on "Request Copy".

In the blue section, an image is supposed to be showing up. It shows up on my Android device and my desktop browser.

Does anyone know why this is not showing up with IOS devices?

[image]

```
    var button_engagement = '';
    $('.requestButton').on('click touchend', function (event) {
        catalogChoice = $(this).data('catalog-name');
        $('.catalogName').html(catalogChoice + ' Catalog');
        event.stopPropagation();
        $('#catalogPop').fadeIn(350);
        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        $('#formWrap').show();
        $('#catalogSuccessWrap').hide();
        $('[name="description').val(catalogChoice);

        var requestButSel = $(this).data('catalog-name');
        var availability = '';
        //Populating the Request Block 1 Img
        if (requestButSel == 'Profile') {
            requestImgLink = 'link';
            requestImgAlt = 'Alt';
        } else if (requestButSel == 'Fastening Technology') {
            requestImgLink = 'link';
            requestImgAlt = 'Alt';
        }
        $('#requestBlock1img').attr('src', requestImgLink);
        $('#requestBlock1img').attr('alt', requestImgAlt);
    });
```

Comment: You have a typo: `$('[name="description')` should be `$('[name="description"]')`

Comment: @KoshVery That actually solved this issue. Thanks! Why would the image be appearing on other devices and not IOS devices with this small typo though?